# Unable to access public IP of application created on aks created with CAF terraform supermodule

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

My goal is to simplify AKS creation using terraform azurerm CAF supermodule.
To accomplish this, i have created https://github.com/mariuszbrz/aks-lx-caf project.
I have created AKS cluster following the README.
Then i have installed ArgoCD with following steps:

```
kubectl create namespace argocd
kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml
```

Then i set public IP for argo-cd service:

```
kubectl edit service argocd-server -n argocd
# change row 40 from
  type: ClusterIP
# to
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I am trying to access the public IP of the ArgoCD service, but can no connection could be established. I can access the resources using private Cluster-IP address.

I have checked the network security groups and looks like all rules are added to allow this traffic.
[image: inbound security rules]

[image: outbound security rules]

Probably i missed something obvious, but still no success with access any application created on this aks cluster using the public IP.

I was trying to troubleshoot the problems using
[connection-issues-application-hosted-aks-cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/connection-issues-application-hosted-aks-cluster)
and
[troubleshoot-network-aks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/operator-guides/aks/troubleshoot-network-aks)
but no luck so far.

Thank You in advance for helping troubleshoot the public IP connection problems.

Comment: the link https://github.com/LUXMED/aks-lx-caf is not working. please check and provide valid one.

Comment: Thank You for info, it could be due to organization access policy, i have shared it via my private github repo (https://github.com/mariuszbrz/aks-lx-caf).